# QualComm Augmented Reality Virtual Button

Tags: android, augmented-reality

i m new in augmented realty so having issues with it. I m using Android SDK from VUFORIA and trying to run the project "Virtual Buttons" sample project when i build it from command prompt using "ndk-build" it build successfully  but when i run the project i crash 
and the log cat says "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/qualcomm/ar/pl/CameraPreview"
does any body got the same issue while running this project ?
 any suggestion/opinion/help will be warmly welcomed 
thank you Usman Arshad Kurd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did the following steps on hit and trial method

Follow these steps to fix the problem:

- Go to your QCAR-based project (e.g. ImageTargets sample app)
- Right-click the project, go to Properties > Java Build Path > Order
  and Export
- Activate the checkbox next to the QCAR JAR file
- Close the project properties
- Clean and rebuild the project